# Linkedin flag as job - php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm trying to flag post-id as job discussion with OAuth PUT :

```
$post_id = "G-34343-example";
$cmd = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{$post_id}/category/code";
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><code>job</code>";
$this->oauthc->fetch($cmd, $xml, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT, array("Content-Type" => "application/xml"));
```

But I'm getting an error:

Someone know what does it mean?

```
com.linkedin.common.leo.core.UnauthorizedActionException: Unauthorized change of forum type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the user you are connecting with using the API authorized to flag posts in the target group? Have you tried logging in to LinkedIn directly as this user, going to the target forum and attempted to flag a post?

Comment: And the user you've authorized granted the [rw_groups](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) permission?

Comment: Yes. I'm posting to group discussions with success (but cannot flagging it).

Comment: Do I need to use the parameter g-4793408-S-203182742 from the response header - "Location: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/g-4793408-S-203182740"

in this way:

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/g-4793408-S-203182742/category/code

in order to flag a post as job?

It's what I'm trying to do and it doesn't work.

Comment: You use the post_id that gets returned by retrieving posts from the group via the API. Yes, the endpoint you are PUTing to is the correct one.

Comment: But how can I reach the specific post which I'm posting?

Comment: You retrieve the posts: [/groups/{group-id}/posts](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#groupposts). The API is meant to have a human perform the actions of flagging, etc, so you would pull the posts, show them to the authenticated user and they would click on 'flag' as needed.

Comment: I want the user will see only his posts. Is there any way to filter by his full name?

Comment: You would have to do the filtering on your side

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies here:

```
<?php
$post id = "G-34343-example";
?>
```

There's a space in the variable name. Use an underscore instead of a whitespace to make it work.

(This: `$cmd = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts/{$post_id}/category/code";` will contain a blank spot where the post id should be.)

Comment: Oh and you should be getting PHP errors from this. Check your error reportring settings.

Comment: Do you have some more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a group post, it's URL is returned in the "location" header. For some reason, the URL from the location header is using http and not https.

If you're using OAuth2, LinkedIn returns a 401 if you try to access the API with http instead of htttps. So if you're getting a 401 response, check that you're using https.

So the code should be something like:

```
$url = $response->headers['location'] . '/category/code';
$url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $post_url);
// ...
```